# Any way to process a string according to format type/ plot data from txt file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, plot, string-formatting

A tab delimited txt file is being read line by line into a list of strings. the aim is to process each word of the string with the format type of the string like datetime or, float or string of characters etc.? so that the data can be plotted . Is there any other efficient way to do this?

```
 using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\\Desktop\snpprivatesellerlist.txt"))
 {
   while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
     char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\n' };
     string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
     {
       st = parts[i];

       // process the line - if part[i] is date time - do something ()
       //                      if part[i] is a float - do something else()

     }
   }
 }
```

Any help and insight is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "can be plotted"?

Comment: Plotted as in into a Graph/Trend

Comment: You are doing a `ReadLine()` and then you are splitting with `'\n'`. Seems odd...shouldn't it be `'\t'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that kinda solved my issue - but i am still working it.

```
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Desktop\snpprivatesellerlist.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                char[] delimiter1 = new char[] { '\n' };
                string[] part1 = line.Split(delimiter1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                for (int i = 0; i < part1.Length; i++)
                {
                    sepList.Add(part1[i]);     
                    //st = part1[i];                       
                }

            }
            file.Close();
        }

        char[] delimiter2 = new char[] { '\t' };
        for (int j = 4; j < sepList.Count; j++)
        {
            st = sepList[j];
            string[] part2 = st.Split(delimiter2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            alist.Add(part2);             
        }

        //DateTime time = new DateTime();
        //float value = new float();

        string tagname = alist[0][0];
        for (int y = 0; y < alist.Count; y++)
        {
             if (alist[y][0]==tagname)
            {
                      alist1.Add(alist[y]);
            }
             else
             {
                SensorProbeDataContainer sensorprobe = new SensorProbeDataContainer();
                sensorprobe.Setdata(templist);                   
                sensorprobe.SensorProbe = sensorprobe.data[0][0];
                ProbeList.Add(sensorprobe.SensorProbe);
                DateTime.TryParse(sensorprobe.data[0][2], out sensorprobe.StartDate);
                DateTime.TryParse(sensorprobe.data[(sensorprobe.data.Count - 1)][2], out sensorprobe.EndDate);
                classcontainer.Add(sensorprobe);
                tagname = alist[y][0];
                templist.Clear();                 }

        }
```

I am trying to follow it on this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719396/iterating-separating-list-of-string-arrays-based-on-first-element

Thanks all for the help. Please do point out if you spot any mistakes in code.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using TryParse, like so...

```
string line;
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Desktop\snpprivatesellerlist.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string st;
        DateTime dtPart;
        float flPart;
        char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\n' };
        string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            st = parts[i];

            if (DateTime.TryParse(st, out dtPart))//Is of type DateTime
            {
                //Do something with DateTime dtPart
            }
            else if (float.TryParse(st, out flPart))//Is of type float
            {
                //Do something with float flPart
            }
            else//Can be considered a string
            {
                //Do something with string st
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Yetti - Thanks Yetti, that is a nice method to put it - i have learnt some thing new.

Answer (score 0):

### If the Fields that come in your tab-delimited file are of the same type always, and no.of fields are fixed.

Then you can create a class of structure to store each line value.

```
class LineData
{    
    public float a {get; set;}
    public DateTime b {get; set;}    
}
```

In the method implementation (i.e. in the `while`):

```
string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);   
//You know 1st column is float, 2nd column is datetime
var dt = new LineData();
float.TryParse(parts[0], out dt.a);
DateTime.TryParse(parts[1], out dt.b);

//...
//store dt in a list/array. (not shown here)
```